# Why do I get Removed["$$Failure"] from FunctionExpand here?

Tags: bugs, simplifying-expressions, special-functions

**Bug introduced in version 11.0 and fixed in 11.1.**

---

Consider the following reduced example:

```
test[r_, n_] = LaguerreL[n, 1/2, r^2];
FunctionExpand[f''[r] /. f -> Function[r, test[r, 0]]]
```

> (2 r^2 Removed[ "$$Failure"] (4/(3 Sqrt[π]) + (
>      E^r^2 (-(3/2) + r^2) (1 - (
>         4 ((E^-r^2 ((3 r^2)/2 + r^4))/Sqrt[r^2] + 
>            3/4 Sqrt[π] (1 - (Sqrt[r^2] Erf[r])/r)))/(
>         3 Sqrt[π])))/(r^2)^(5/2)))/Sqrt[π]

Note the `Removed[ "$$Failure"]` term in the answer. This appears to result from attempt to `FunctionExpand` a term of `LaguerreL[-2, 1/2, x]`. But how does this term even appear in the first place? A simple change of the above code yields me `0`:

```
FunctionExpand[f''[r] /. f -> Function[r, Evaluate@test[r, 0]]]
```

> 0

So it seems `test` isn't evaluated in original example, but is somehow differentiated... What's happening here?

Comment: I don't get any error when running your code (v10.0.1); it seems to work for me (well, it returns 0; i'm not sure if it's supposed to). Have you tried quitting the kernel?

Comment: @march Even starting new Mathematica instance still gives me this result. I'm using v11.0. It does appear to work in versions 7 through 10.

Comment: Strikes me as a bug then.

Comment: No error under `10.4.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit)`.

Comment: Definitely new to version 11.

Comment: @Ruslan  Will you inform Wolfram, Inc of this bug, or shall I?

Comment: @bgodfrey et al This has been reported and will be fixed in a future release (quite likely the next one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here can be traced to an error in evaluating `Pochhammer[-1, a]`, with `a` a rational (i.e., infinite precision) number.  To begin, determine

```
f''[r] /. f -> Function[r, LaguerreL[0, 1/2, r^2]]
(* 4 r^2 LaguerreL[-2, 5/2, r^2] - 2 LaguerreL[-1, 3/2, r^2] *)
```

The second term, proportional to `LaguerreL[-1, 3/2, r^2]`, is identically `0`, as can be seen by applying `FunctionExpand[]` or `FullSimplify[]` to it.  So, focus on `LaguerreL[-2, 5/2, r^2]`, and replace `5/2` by `a` for now.

```
FunctionExpand[LaguerreL[-2, a, r^2]] // Simplify
(* ((r^2)^-a ((r^2)^a + E^r^2 (1 - a + r^2) Gamma[a] - 
   E^r^2 (1 - a + r^2) Gamma[a, r^2]) Pochhammer[-1, a])/Gamma[a] *)
```

which is proportional to `Pochhammer[-1, a]`, and

```
Pochhammer[-1, 5/2]
(* Removed["$$Failure"]/(2 Sqrt[π]) *)
```

In fact, every rational number I have tried for `a` yields a result containing `Removed["$$Failure"]`.  On the other hand,

```
Pochhammer[-1, 2.5]
(* -3.45466*10^-17 *)
```

and

```
Pochhammer[-1, SetPrecision[2.5, 30]]
(* 0.*10^-30 *)
```

Evidently, `Pochhammer[-1, a]` should be identically `0`.  As noted by [Daniel Lichtblau](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/51/daniel-lichtblau), this bug is new to version 11.  In 10.4.1, `Pochhammer[-1, 5/2]` evaluates to `0`.

Incidentally, `FunctionExpand[f''[r] /. f -> Function[r, Evaluate@test[r, 0]]]` yields `0`, as noted in the question, because `Evaluate@test[r, 0]` is identically `1`, as it should be.

Comment: So, how I understand it: in the error case `LaguerreL` is never evaluated before being differentiated, and then, still unevaluated, it's expanded by `FunctionExpand`, and only then the evaluation takes place. This lets the problem with `Pochhammer` appear visible. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Ruslan  Apparently so.